# Tips and tricks for presentation demo for academic job interview

Tags: presentation, tenure-track, interview

I am working on different research projects. I was asked to give research demo on an on-campus interview. I am thinking of the two following strategies:

First is to give overview of the projects I worked on (one or 2 slides), and then present in detail one of my latest published papers.

Another one is to give a overview of papers for each project with not going in depth.

I am wondering about the best way to impress the research committee. I am working in very hot areas in computer science. If there is any presentation/demos to share, I would be very thankful

Comment: Good to avoid too many typoze on slides...

Comment: Probably either is fine provided that teaching isn't a big part of the job.

Comment: Think about your audience! I think that's your biggest challenge. E.g. your post doesn't even specify what kind of job you are applying for. How are we supposed to know? Always put yourself into the shoes off your audience. The rest will follow... Good luck!

Comment: A word of caution: In my experience, candidates who try too hard to impress, or appear to oversell their work, inevitably end up irking a few senior faculty members.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your strategies are probably fine, but they both seem focused on the past. What you have already done. Don't neglect the future. What are you working on now that shows promise? And, for some situations, how you can possibly include others, faculty and grad students, into a research program. Think about the job as a whole and the university department as a whole.